# Find the derived group of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory

> Find the derived group of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$

I believe that the derived group is $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$, as it is easy to see that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})' \subset SL(n,\mathbb{R})$, since for any $A,B \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$,  we get that $det(ABA^{-1}B^{-1})=1$, and therefore $ABA^{-1}B^{-1} \in SL(n, \mathbb{R})$.

However, I'm not sure how to prove that other side - $ SL(n,\mathbb{R}) \subset  GL(n,\mathbb{R})'$?

Comment: Try to compute the commutator of two transvections $I_n + aE_{i,j}, i\neq j$

Comment: The question has been answered already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311331/sl-n-mathbb-r-is-a-subgroup-of-kernel-of-f-in-homgl-n-mathbb-r-a/2312153), see the answer of Hamio Jiang.

Comment: @Dietrich Brude thank you.